# Parsing XML with DOMParser works in Chrome, but not in FF

Tags: javascript, xml, google-chrome, firefox, domparser

I am trying to get a node from XML using DOMParser. The code below works in Chrome, but not in FF. Am I doing something wrong? Or, is FF doing something wrong? A fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/lborgman/D8QHT/2/

```
var zXml = '<?xml version="1.0"?> <div class="csl-bib-body" style="line-height: 2; padding-left: 2em; text-indent:-2em;"> <div class="csl-entry">The Polyvagal Theory.</div> </div>';
var dp = new DOMParser();
var zDom = dp.parseFromString(zXml, "text/xml");
document.getElementById("output").appendChild(document.createTextNode(zDom.nodeValue));
var divCite = zDom.querySelector("div.csl-entry");
console.log(divCite);
document.getElementById("output2").appendChild(document.createTextNode(divCite.innerHTML));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try parsing as `text/html`: the `querySelector` doesn't work on an XML document because XML doesn't understand CSS classes.

```
var zDom = dp.parseFromString(zXml, "text/html");
```

Alternatively, you can use XML and querySelector, but be more explicit with your selector argument:

```
var divCite = zDom.querySelector("div[class=csl-entry]");
```

As for the `nodeValue`, I'm not sure what you expect to see in that property of a `document` object.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy! Parsing as `text/html` makes it work in FF too. A bit confusing, of course. It looks to me like the Chrome way is better.

Comment: Actually I have to disagree: I think it's a bit weird to expect the CSS shorthand syntax to properly query an XML document. (That's why I added the `[class=...` selector to my answer.) Still, we made it work which is the important thing.